# How to debug if echo $this->getChildHtml() returns nothing in live

Tags: magento-1.9

i'm printing `echo $this->getChildHtml('myview');` in product listing page. With the codes below

In catalog.xml

```
<block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list"....
     <block type="core/template" name="myview" template="compareview/compareview.phtml" />
</block>
```

I have build the view file(with just a text content for now) and located on the template path i have mentioned. And this works for me in local but it's blank in live/remove. How can i debug this or where did i go wrong ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possible reasons that the *same code* works on one system and not on another:

1. You are using symlinks (for example with modman) and the "Allow symlinks" setting in "System > Configuration > Developer > Template" is turned off
2. The template file is not readable. Check the file permissions and see `var/system.log` for "missing template" error messages (enable logging in "System > Configuration > Developer" if necessary)
3. The one-size-fits-all answer: Did you clean the cache?